# CarouselView not rendering on initial page load but renders on XAML Hot Reload

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to add a CarouselView to display the images the user has picked from their device. Upon debugging, after picking files the CarouselView does not render with the images I've chosen, not even the Frame itself is rendered. After messing around with the XAML, I realized that the CarouselView actually does exist and when I just save the XAML file while debugging, XAML Hot Reload kicks in and the CarouselView renders perfectly.

Here is my XAML code for the CarouselView:

```
<CarouselView x:Name="preview" IsVisible="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Files}">
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Frame  HasShadow="True"
                               IsVisible="True"
                               BorderColor="Black"
                               CornerRadius="5"
                               Margin="20"
                               HeightRequest="500"
                               WidthRequest="500"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               VerticalOptions="Start">
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding FileName}"></Label>
                                <Image Source="{Binding FullPath}"
                                       Aspect="AspectFill"
                                       HeightRequest="500"
                                       WidthRequest="500"
                                       VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>
```

and here is the code behind:

```
public FileView( IEnumerable<FileResult> pF)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
        this.pickedFiles = pF;
    }

    private IEnumerable<FileResult> pickedFiles;
    public IEnumerable<FileResult> Files
    {
        get => pickedFiles;
    }
```

I am utilizing a FileResult object as part of the Xamarin.Essentials plugin to get the files form the device, I've successfully binded the filepath and file name from each file into the CarouselView. The issues i'm facing now is that it's not rendering on the first attempt.

Tested on an Android device if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you can use `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>`, because [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-5.0) implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface, to notify the view when data changed or update.

the code behind, you can take a look:

```
public partial class Page2 : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<FileResult> Files { get; set; }   
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Files = new ObservableCollection<FileResult>();
        loaddata();
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
    private void loaddata()
    {
        Files.Add(new FileResult() { FileName="image 1",FullPath="a5.jpg"});
        Files.Add(new FileResult() { FileName = "image 2", FullPath = "a6.jpg" });
        Files.Add(new FileResult() { FileName = "image 3", FullPath = "a7.jpg" });
        Files.Add(new FileResult() { FileName = "image 4", FullPath = "a8.jpg" });
        Files.Add(new FileResult() { FileName = "image 5", FullPath = "a9.jpg" });
    }
}

public class FileResult
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FullPath { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried using a  `ObservableCollection<FileResult>` but it's still the same issue, I have to XAML Hot Reload to see the carouselview. I modified your sample code a bit to still use an `IEnumerable<T>` to populate the `ObservableCollection<T>` and then accessing the `ObservableCollection<T>` instead on my XAML Binding but no luck.

Comment: Upon messing around some more, I changed the position of my `this.BindingContext = this` to be under my `ObservableCollection<T>` instantiation and it works! I even tried it with the original `IEnumerable<T>` and it also works. Turns out it was a problem of setting the BindingContext too early! Thanks for the help, marking this as the answer